# How to display a picture (saved on a nodejs server) in an ionic/angular app?

Tags: node.js, angular, image, ionic-framework

I would like to display an image in my ionic (angular) app. My picture is stored on my server. I see two ways of doing it:

- give directly the url: `<img src="url" />`
- load the image as a blob: `<img src="blob" />`

The two ways are working but I would like to know if one is better than the other in terms of rapidity, accessibility, safety, ...

The angular service:

```
getMedia(hashId: string) {
    return this.httpClient
      .get(`${this.baseRoute}/media`, {
        responseType: 'blob',
      })
      .pipe(
        mergeMap((media: any) => {
          if (media && media.size > 0) {
            let reader = new FileReader();

            if (media) {
              reader.readAsDataURL(media);
            }

            return fromEvent(reader, 'load').pipe(map(() => reader.result));
          } else {
            return of(null);
          }
        }),
        catchError((error) => throwError(error))
      );
  }
```

The other side in nodejs/express:

```
getImage(req, res) {
        var imageDirectoryPath = path.join(__dirname, "../pictures", req.params.hashId);

        fs.readdir(imageDirectoryPath, function (error, fileNames) {
            if (error) {
                res.status(200).json(undefined);
            } else {
                if (fileNames.length > 0) {
                    var fileName = fileNames[0];
                    if (!fileName) {
                        res.status(200).json(undefined);
                        return;
                    }
                    const filePath = path.join(imageDirectoryPath, fileName);
                    res.sendFile(filePath);
                } else {
                    res.status(200).json(undefined);
                }
            }
        });
    },
```

Comment: go the URL Route.